# Multiple select count(*) statements that have their own row in resultset

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I want to build a single query that will do several count(*)s using different regexes. Currently, they all come out as one long row, but I want each of the counts to be in the result set as their own row.

I have:

```
select 
    (select count(*) from table where text rlike 'genetics') as genetics,
    (select count(*) from table where text rlike 'biology') as biology;
```

Which gives 'genetics', and 'biology' as the column titles and the counts as row 1 values.
the same 'text' can be counted in the separate counts, it's not needed to be unique to only one count total. I only want one result set. Using Mysql version 5.1.52.

Comment: "I only want one result set." Don't you get one result set with two columns? What is the shape of the result set that you would like to get?

Comment: Sorry. I would like to get one set, with the counts being in one column, and the regex phrases being in another, given some name. So, say:<br/>


regex    | count<br/>
----------------<br/>
genetics | 40<br/>
biology  | 32

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to get one set, with the counts being in one column, and the regex phrases being in another, given some name.

Here is one way of doing this:

```
select regex, count(*)
from test t
join (
    select 'biology' regex
        union all
    select 'genetics' regex
) r ON t.text rlike r.regex
group by r.regex
```

The idea is to join the actual table `test` with an "impromptu table" formed by `UNION`-ing two string literals into a set of rows, and calling them `regex`. Joining criterion uses `rlike` condition from your query.

This produces a Cartesian product of regex-es and texts that they match. Applying `GROUP BY` lets you produce the result that you want ([demo.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff021/2)).

Comment: This'll do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use `union all`:

```
(select count(*) from table where text rlike 'genetics')
union all
(select count(*) from table where text rlike 'biology')
```

I would suggest you add another column specifying where the data is coming from.

In fact, I would recommend a `group by`:

```
select text, count(*)
from table
group by text;
```

You can optionally include `where text in ('genetics', 'biology')`.